# Pandas - change string to a number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with a lot of email and I want change this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [('aatest@gmail.com', 0, 3.0), ('aatest@gmail.com', 1, 2.0), 
                    ('aatest@gmail.com', 1 ,3.0), ('bbtest@gmail.com', 1, 1.0), 
                    ('cctest@gmail.com', 2, 5.0)]) 

df
0  aatest@gmail.com  0  3
1  aatest@gmail.com  1  2
2  aatest@gmail.com  1  3
3  bbtest@gmail.com  1  1
4  cctest@gmail.com  2  5
```

to this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
[(0, 0, 3.0), (0, 1, 2.0), (0,1 ,3.0), (1, 1, 1.0), (2, 2, 5.0)])

df2
   0  1  2
0  0  0  3
1  0  1  2
2  0  1  3
3  1  1  1
4  2  2  5
```

i.e, change the email to a number, but the same email stay with the same number

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df[0] = pd.factorize(df[0])[0]

print df

   0  1  2
0  0  0  3
1  0  1  2
2  0  1  3
3  1  1  1
4  2  2  5
```

Or [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df[0] = df[0].rank(method='dense') - 1
print df

   0  1  2
0  0  0  3
1  0  1  2
2  0  1  3
3  1  1  1
4  2  2  5
```